# Why can't we use the well known [code] and [quote] tags to markup our posts?

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, blockquote

Personally, when creating posts, I find it very frustrating not to be able to effectively mark a quotation as we normally would in the vast majority of forums. Simply being able to do it using [quote][/quote] would be ideal.

It's also exceptionally tedious to have to go through every line of posted code, adding four spaces at the beginning of each line (except wrapped ones). Why can't we simply use [code][/code]?

The lack of these basic features will sometimes cause me to ask elsewhere.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [editing help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), [Markdown syntax specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). There's even an inline help telling you how to do everything if you click the question mark above the input field.

Comment: "Why can't we use the well known [code] and [quote] tags to markup our posts?" Because we use Markdown, not BBCode.

Comment: Hold up. Wait. You've been a member for 4 days, asked 2 questions, both perfectly formatted, and yet it causes you to rather ask elsewhere? Not sure if this is a valid argument right there. Repeat after me: **SE is not a forum**

Comment: I was always able to deal with BBcode. Until I started using markdown. Now I know better.

Comment: Hmm, **because they're not well-known**? For example, I've never heard of them.

Answer (score 11):

To add the four spaces for code simply highlight the block of text and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or select the `{}` icon. This will format all the lines of code for you.

To quote just add a single `>` to the beginning of the **first line** of each paragraph you want to quote. There's no need to do it on every line. Alternatively, just highlight the block of text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or select the `"` icon.

For example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

This is just

`> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum`

Comment: thanks did not know that. shame on me :P

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! After reading the comments above I was beginning lose hope. Your comment gave me exactly what I needed. Will try to remember those, since that is not what I understand by reading all the paragraphs of text which appear when you click the code or quote button.

Maybe they should replace their long-winded instructions with your yours (or better still, make the code and quote button just do it).